# Ubuntu 18.04. wifi on T450s - no adapter found after deleting iwlconfig

Tags: drivers, wireless, 18.04

I have a T450s and run Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. I had problems with my wifi card Intel 7265 and nothing helped. So I deleted all "iwl..." files from /lib/firmware and put new drivers in there "iwlwifi-7265-14.ucode" and "iwlwifi-7265D-14.ucode".

Now my system does not detect any wifi adapter at all. I googled a lot, but nothing seems to help.

Here are some logs:

```
    dominik@dominik-ThinkPad-T450s:~$ nmcli radio wifi
    enabled
```

running ifconfig

```
:~$ ifconfig
enp0s25: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.30.8.243  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 10.30.255.255
        inet6 fe80::b079:19e0:d069:43df  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 50:7b:9d:61:f5:6c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 8333  bytes 4221893 (4.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 13  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3638  bytes 518426 (518.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xf1200000-f1220000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 982  bytes 134055 (134.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 982  bytes 134055 (134.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

running iwconfig

```
    dominik@dominik-ThinkPad-T450s:~$ iwconfig
enp0s25   no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Does anyone have an idea? Thank so so much!

Comment: Deleting firmware files was a wrong move. Not sure what you've expected.

Comment: Definitively, I expected to be able to replace firmware drivers. With „sudo rm iwlwifi-*“ I expected all drivers regarding the WiFi adapter to be removed. Afterwards I put the correct drivers back into the folder ...

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I downloaded iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode and put it into /lib/firmware ... now I see WiFi networks again but it seems to be very unstable ... with my mobile I have a good connection to the WiFi which my laptop doesn’t even see. Basically my WiFi doesn’t work at all even if the computer sees the adapter